# EF Core, OData v4, Automapper - Null reference exception when querying with nested $expand

Tags: c#, odata, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.1

I'm having a strange issue that I've been struggling with for days.

I have a project where I am using OData to access entity sets that are DTOs mapped by Automapper from Entity Framework entities. This is all on an ASP.NET Core Web API project.

I have a specific setup where it's causing problems.

- An entity with a 1:1 child, which itself has a 1:1 child, both relationships are optional.
- The entity set that I'm querying exists but has null relationships with the other two.
- I query with OData's `/api/Foos$expand=man($expand=chu)`.
- This results in a null reference exception.

The full output from ASP.NET Core Web Server is located here - https://gist.github.com/nickspiers/3620840145d0a88e3966643613a5d442

A recreation of the issue in it's simplest form is here - https://github.com/nickspiers/efcore-issue

I tried to boil everything down to it's simplest parts but if there's more information I'm forgetting, please just let me know what else I can provide. Thanks!

Comment: If someone is interested in a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64177122/6297069
But please share if there is a real solution

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, now head over to the Odata and Entity Framework Core github sites and be shocked.

Sadly there is nothing you can do. TOMS of bugs - EF Core is hardly usable in certain scenarios.

Official stance is tha this liekly all gets ifxed in the 3.0 timeframe - which you likly can use Summer 2019. No joke. Before that the whole bunch of LINQ issues they have are pushed back.2.1 - not important. 2.2 - small release, not hard linq work. Have fun waiting.

Same place here.

I opened a discussion about it here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12953

Answers include:

> Query is lacking test coverage. We are working on this on a few
> fronts, but it is not a small amount of work, and takes resources away
> from adding features or fixing bugs--one reason 2.2 is a smaller
> release. One part of this will be making easier for people to submit
> tests.

And

> It has become apparent that using OData causes certain query patterns
> to be more common than would be the case if the queries were written
> by hand. This makes it particularly prone to lack of test coverage.

OData WebApi has an open issue for that too.

Right now the only sensible workaround may be:

- Change project type to net472
- Use Asp.net etc. NOT in dotnet core
- Which allows you to use modern asp.net but Entity Framework.

6.2 may be old, may be "not having all the bells and whistles" - but it has WAY fewer bugs on the LINQ side and is actually usable in this scenario.

This is at the core NOT an OData issue - the LINQ is valid. It is totally an EF Core product issue, which was released with GLARING problems on the translation/provider site which are all not handled with any prioerity but seem to be backlogged for 3.0

Now, in your particular case - you do a ProjectTo, right? TO you take the includes in there? Ef Core has issues otherwise. Yes, no joke. But there is code out in the publich to extract the needed Includes, which you can use. You definitely need to extract the includes and then use them in ProjectTo.

I use that and a second part (checking whether certain constructs are in) the check whether I return an IQUeryable directly, or do a ToList first (which then results in in memory handling - inefficient ,but some things need it).

EDIT:

As of .Net 5 many of the automapper issues have been improved and a new extension package  `AutoMapper.Extensions.OData` is available which brings in testing improvements, .Net api controller abstract classes and attributes like `ODataController` and `[EnableQuery]`. See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData for details.

Comment: I do use ProjectTo, and adding the includes doesn't seem to help. I'm currently using ToList as a workaround but like you said - very inefficient. If nobody answers with anything else, I'll probably looking at switching to EF 6.2 like you suggest until the core version is more mature and stable.

Comment: If anyone answers andthing better I gladly implement it. I love Odata, but the currnent stack is plagued by a ridiculous amount of errors on every level. And EF Core is right in the middle and likely repsonsible for 75% of the issues.

Comment: I understand your pain - luckily I'm just monitoring EF Core from outside (not using it in production). It would be interesting to know what does OData query add on top of the EF query, since the pure `ProjectTo` + `ToLIst()` works just fine in 2.1.1

Comment: Nothing. It is not about adding - Odata basically exposes a query syntax, so you can then filter and include through the URL in a standard way which tools support. This gets transported into starndard linq. If you remove ToList then yo uget.... hey, PERFORMANCE. Which ToList does not have. Some of us run that on large data - if you can filter a million entries down on the sql level with the query coming from odata and avoid the ToList... hey, performance.

Comment: I understand that. The question was more out of curiosity, what LINQ construct on top of a `ProjectTo` (basically `Select`) EF query confuses EF Core query translator and/or processor. But anyway, I found that myself - the conditional object projection somehow breaks when secondary projection is applied on top of it.  Yeah, EFC query part is far far from what it should be (or used to be in EF6). I like the elegance of EFC generated queries, but when they don't work it really doesn't matter. Too bad they concentrate on other stuff.