# How to combine OData 4 and Automapper in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, odata, automapper

I try to combine Automapper and OData in .NET Core 3.1, but I have been stuck for a while now. My OData controller works like a charm this way:

```
[ODataRoute]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Unit> Get()
{
    return _context.Units;
}
```

`_context` is my EF `DbContext`.

However, I need to expose a `UnitDto` instead of `Unit`.

What I tried so far is:

```
[ODataRoute]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<UnitDto> Get()
{
    var units = _context.Units;
    return units.ProjectTo<UnitDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
}
```

But that results into a null reference exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.AsyncEnumerableReader.ReadInternal[T](Object value)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.AsyncEnumerableReader.ReadInternal[T](Object value)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncEnumerable(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Object asyncEnumerable, Func`2 reader)
> etc.

Using `GetQueryAsync` of `Automapper.Aspnetcore.Odata.EFCore` results in the same exception:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(ODataQueryOptions<UnitDto> options)
{
    return Ok(await _context.Units.GetQueryAsync(_mapper, options));
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Is this the way to go and am I doing something wrong or should I go another direction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end I was able to find a workaround. So assuming more people have this issue, here is what I did to make it work.

The first thing is to execute the query on the database objects. Then get their results (using JSON (de)serialization, did not know a better way) and map them to the DTO object.

```
[ODataRoute]
[EnableCustomQuery]
public IEnumerable<UnitDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Unit> opts)
{
       var queryResult = opts.ApplyTo(_context.Units);

       var units = _mapper.Map<List<Unit>>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UnitOData>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult)));

       return _mapper.Map<List<UnitDto>>(units);
 }
```

The thing is I want to use all queryoptions including `$expand`, `$filter`, `$skip`, `$top` and `$count`. But the query should be on the database object whereas it is queried upon the DTO objects. Therefore I linked it in my EDM model like this:

```
var unitsConfig = builder.EntitySet<Unit>("UnitsWithoutDto");
unitsConfig.EntityType.Property(p => p.InternalReference).Name = "ExternalReference";
```

The result of the deserialize will now be the database object with one property changed when that specific one is filtered upon. Therefore I created a new `UnitOData`.

```
public class UnitOData : Unit
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

And mapped it to the original object depending on whether the specific property exists.

```
CreateMap<UnitOData, Unit>()
     .ForMember(a => a.InternalReference, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ExternalReference ?? src.InternalReference));
```

Then everything works fine expect the paging. So a created a custom filter that ignores the `$skip` and the `$top` query options.

```
public class EnableCustomQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var ignoreQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Skip | AllowedQueryOptions.Top;
        return queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable, ignoreQueryOptions);
    }
}
```

Please share if there is a real solution.